# Security update for patched module

Tags: 8

Is it necessary to re-patch an existing patched module when doing a security update for that module?  I am not interested in keeping it patched. Or will this potentially break something?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need to repatch the module, if you doing it manually.

If are using [composer to manage your drupal set up](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies), you can use "[cweagans/composer-patches](https://packagist.org/packages/cweagans/composer-patches)", and this composer plugin it will reapply the patch for you automatically and let you know if the patch will no longer work on the newer version of the module.

This is a big time saver.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is for Drupal 7.  It is the Entity Connect module. If I reapply existing patch will this negate anything that the security update provides? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what the patch is.  Is it on Drupal.org?  Do you want to add this info to the ticket so we can give you a better answer?

Comment: Yes, it is a Drupal contrib module.  I have Entity connect 7.x-1.0-rc1+7-dev (2014-Apr-01) installed, which is no longer supported.  The recommended version is 7.x2.0-rc1 (2016-Jul-18).  This is a security update.  If a version is no longer supported, would a patch applied to it serve any purpose in the updated version? I am trying to stay away from re-patching this module, if I am able to. Thanks again. Much appreciated.